# Room migration is failing IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-room

I am now trying to migrate to a new version in room. I have changed 1 variable and removed one row.

Migration function

```
    static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE timereport_table_new (" +
                "id INTEGER, " +
                "company_name TEXT, " +
                "salary REAL, " +
                "hour_salary REAL, " +
                "hours REAL, " +
                "ob_hours REAL, " +
                "ob_hour_salary TEXT," +
                "unpaid_brake REAL," +
                "have_worked INTEGER," +
                "worked_date TEXT )");

        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO timereport_table_new (" +
                "id, " +
                "company_name, " +
                "salary, " +
                "hour_salary," +
                "hours," +
                "ob_hours," +
                "ob_hour_salary," +
                "unpaid_brake," +
                "have_worked," +
                "worked_date) SELECT id, company_name, salary, hour_salary, hours, ob_hours, ob_salary, unpaid_brake, have_worked, worked_Date FROM timereport_table");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE timereport_table");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE timereport_table_new RENAME TO timereport_table");
    }
};
```

Part of model class (showing only the variables)
Trying to change double obSalary; to String obSalary;
and remove //double obSalaryPercent; from table.

```
......
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@NonNull int id;
@ColumnInfo(name = "company_name")
String companyName;
double salary;
@ColumnInfo(name = "hour_salary")
double hourSalary;
double hours;
@ColumnInfo(name = "ob_hours")
double obHours;
@ColumnInfo(name = "ob_hour_salary")
double obSalary;
//@ColumnInfo(name = "ob_percent")
//double obSalaryPercent;
@ColumnInfo(name = "unpaid_brake")
double unpaidBrake;
@ColumnInfo(name = "have_worked")
Boolean haveWorked;
@ColumnInfo(name = "worked_date")
String workedDate;
......
```

Getting following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_0
Process: com.example.worktime, PID: 7721
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
    at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: timereport_table(com.example.worktime.models.TimeReportModel).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='timereport_table', columns={hour_salary=Column{name='hour_salary', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, hours=Column{name='hours', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, company_name=Column{name='company_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, unpaid_brake=Column{name='unpaid_brake', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, have_worked=Column{name='have_worked', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ob_hour_salary=Column{name='ob_hour_salary', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, salary=Column{name='salary', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ob_hours=Column{name='ob_hours', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, worked_date=Column{name='worked_date', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='timereport_table', columns={hour_salary=Column{name='hour_salary', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, hours=Column{name='hours', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, company_name=Column{name='company_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, unpaid_brake=Column{name='unpaid_brake', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, have_worked=Column{name='have_worked', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ob_hour_salary=Column{name='ob_hour_salary', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, salary=Column{name='salary', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, ob_hours=Column{name='ob_hours', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, worked_date=Column{name='worked_date', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:103)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nullable status of each field of your new table must match the status declared in your entity.  Java primative types are implicitly non-nullable.

Also, the type of `obSalary` is inconsistent.  Declared as `double` in your entity, `TEXT` in your new table.

```
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE timereport_table_new (" +
            "id INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "company_name TEXT, " +
            "salary REAL NOT NULL, " +
            "hour_salary REAL NOT NULL, " +
            "hours  REAL NOT NULL, " +
            "ob_hours REAL NOT NULL, " +
            "ob_hour_salary REAL NOT NULL," + // <- changed to REAL
            "unpaid_brake REAL NOT NULL," +
            "have_worked INTEGER," +
            "worked_date TEXT )");
```

Comment: hi can you help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243505/how-to-fetch-edittext-value-from-one-activity-to-recyclerview-of-next-activity#63243505